# what are the supported synonym in action.devices.traits.FanSpeed

Tags: actions-on-google

As the docs https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/fanspeed not say what speed_synonym is allowed (no reference list), and "speed 1", "speed 2" of the example not work, juts "low", "high" work. "1", "2", "3" ... also not work. So the question is what speed_synonym is valid in fanspeed traits ?

Answer (score 0):

Any key and synonyms should work for a particular language for the FanSpeed trait. Low/High work, as per the example, but I've also gotten 1/2/3/4 to work for the `speed_name` field. You may want to inflate your `speed_synonym` field to have more synonyms which will trigger.

Comment: could you please help me check this FanSpeed trait https://pastebin.com/dZwR7CVC. Set fan speed of [name] to {speed 1/two/4/5} not work. Set fan speed of [name] to {low/medium/high/auto/quiet} work. Could you give me the FanSpeed trait so Set fan speed of [name] to {1/2/3/4/5/low/medium/high/auto/quiet} work. Thanks.

Comment: You should the transcriptions that you're sending. It's probably not picking up the speed name correctly.

Comment: please show me an FanSpeed trait config that make "set fan speed of [name] to 1" work, I try so much but nothing work, please help me @Nick Felker, thanks.